# Where can my "out of the box" program create directory reliably in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

For example, if my program tries to create a directory using [CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\[install directory]\`, it will fail due to permissions issues.

I have heard that the ideal location is `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\`, but are there other "safe" locations?

Of course it may vary depending on the version of Windows.

Comment: Aaron Margosis used to write a blog that might be relevant here, specifically this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/09/25/faq-where-do-i-save-files-and-how-exactly-do-i-do-that.aspx

Comment: You can `getenv` the `HOME` variable. Then follow the convention of the operating system to get a directory for yourself. In Linux that could be `HOME/.your_program` or in Windows `HOME/AppData/Local/your_program` (I don't really know about Windows). What I meant is to create a directory under `HOME` to be sure you have permission (and to be able to find it later too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\ProgramData is other location which is used commonly.
This below is helpfull,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a way to determine machine specific Temp folder? Then this should be usefull:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx